# CRUD actions in a SharePoint MsLists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, api, wsdl, mslists

We are trying to automate some actions, which are now handled manually.
The thing we try to achieve is to insert automatically data from a webform into a new MsLists line.

For this we need to connect to the WSDL (SOAP) or (REST API).

The problem is that I found out some tutorials which require authentication / tokens but it's only valid for a short period.

I want to make it possible to use PHP/JS for doing CRUD operations in MsLists.

Currently my list is located at:

```
https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/msteams_xxxxxx/Lists/demo/AllItems.aspx
```

I saw some packages that need a WSDL file (SOAP), but I have no idea where to find it in SharePoint. ( https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API#installation )

Is there someone who can help me a bit out with this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Where have you created your form? On SharePoint page or in external application?

Comment: @GaneshSanap This is an external application. Thank you.